# Perform subtraction within regular expression

Tags: ruby, regex

I have the following RSpec output:

```
30 examples, 15 failures
```

I would like to subtract the second number from the first. I have this code:

```
def capture_passing_score(output)
  captures = output.match(/^(?<total>\d+)\s*examples,\s*(?<failed>\d+)\s*failures$/)
  captures[:total].to_i - captures[:failed].to_i
end
```

I am wondering if there is a way to do the calculation within a regular expression. Ideally, I'd avoid the second step in my code, and subtract the numbers within a regex. Performing mathematical operations may not be possible with Ruby's (or any) regex engine, but I couldn't find an answer either way. Is this possible?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you post an example of what `output` which might be passed to your method looks like?

Comment: The example of what `output` could be is the first text snippet in my post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope.

By every definition I have ever seen, Regular Expressions are about text processing. It is character based pattern matching. Numbers are a class of textual characters in Regex and do not represent their numerical values. While [syntactic sugar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) may mask what is actually being done, you still need to convert the text to a numeric value to perform the subtraction.

[WikiPedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)

[RubyDoc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Regexp.html)

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Regex doesn't care that the numbers have some _value_, it just sees them a "some numeric character". Appreciate the clarification

Answer (score 1):

If you know the format is going to remain consistent, you could do something like this:

```
output.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i).inject(:-)
```

It's not doing the subtraction via regex, but it does make it more concise.

Comment: This is nice an simple. However, benchmark vs OPs original method, this is actually about 50% less performant.  Sometimes less code is not fastest code.